# How can I add audio message in my android application?

Tags: android, audio, android-activity

I want to give audio message at the opening of my android application just like "Welcome our System" but i can't.

**code:**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

            String text="Welcome to our location based system";
            if (text!=null && text.length()>0)              
            {
                Toast.makeText(SimpleAudioTestActivity.this, "Saying: " + text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
            }                       

    Intent checkintent=new Intent();
    checkintent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(checkintent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
}
```

When I do it after clicking a button it is ok:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        but1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        but1.setonclickListener(new View.onclickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onclick(View arg0) 
            {
                String text="Welcome to our location based system";
                if (text!=null && text.length()>0)              
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SimpleAudioTestActivity.this, "Saying: " + text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                }                       
            }
        });           

        Intent checkintent=new Intent();
        checkintent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkintent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
    }
```

How can I do that? Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your audio file (such as mp3 file) in `res/raw` folder then create `MediaPlayer` and play that file

Comment: i want to make it by text to speech conversion for why in my code i took a string that will be converted to audio......

Comment: Why do you want text to speech for the text that seems to never change? Also, text to speech will require internet connection.

Comment: i don't need to change the message. i already did it after clicking a button in my app but can't for starting of app. is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?  This code will speak whatever is in the string 'text' using texttospeech.  Place it in your onCreate.

```
TextToSpeech speak;


speak = new TextToSpeech(TextTalk.this,
            new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

                @Override
                public void onInit(int status) {
                    if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                        speak.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                    }
                }
            });

speak.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

Comment: Check [This](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-a-really-easy-tutorial-on-how-to-use-text-to-speech-tts-and-how-you-can-enter-text-and-have-it-spoken/), it should help.

Comment: In this code when i tried to setLanguage by TextToSpeech object there is no output and my String for output can't do that for another language. In your code sayText.setLanguage(Locale.US) sayText means what?

Comment: Sorry I meant for that to be speak.

Comment: thanks for your help. How can i change the default language such as i want to set japan language i tried many times but can't.

Comment: where it says speak.setLanguage(Locale.US);  Change US to JAPAN.  Also, when your question is answered, please pick a best answer so that we can move on from your question.